# Use Coldfusion query resultset in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coldfusion

I'm trying to use AngularJS in my cfm files to display data from cfquery resultset.
I used below code in my cfm file.I'm not able to see any output.
P.S. I'm really new to AngularJS. So if anyone can please help me out here it would be great.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html ng-app="Demo">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Applications/_Common/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">
    <CF_GetProjectData project_number=349246 query_name="GetProject">
      <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <div ng-repeat="number in project">
          {{number.project_number}} - {{number.project_name}}
        </div>
        <!-- <input name="imprint" type="text" size="10" ng-model="first">
        <p>{{first}}</p> -->
      </div>

      <cfoutput>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/wddx.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script language="text/javascript">
          var theProjectArray; < cfwddx action = "CFML2JS"
          input = "#GetProject#"
          toplevelvariable = "theProjectArray" >
        </script>
        <script>
          var Demo = angular.module("Demo", []);
          Demo.controller("DemoController", function($scope) {
            $scope.project = theProjectArray;
            alert(theProjectArray);
          });
        </script>
      </cfoutput>

      <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you get in the `alert()` which contains `theProjectArray`?

Comment: @Starscream1984 nothing. I just get a blank page. no alerts.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no errors in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about Angular.js but based on the code you have posted, it seems, you need to wrap `ng-controller` `div` in `cfoutput`. This is because you have set `enablecfoutputonly="Yes"`. So only the content inside `cfoutput` will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a CF developer that's currently learning Angular as well.  First of all Angular is a MVC framework and will work for you best of you follow the rules of Separation of Concern (SoC).  I know unless you are using Object Relational Mapping (ORM) in CF this is counter intuitive but it will save you so much hassle and trouble shooting later.

For your problem right now though i would

1. combine both script blocks.
2. your variable theProjectArray is defined with var so it's not
   global.  Are you sure it's making it into your controller?
3. the line toplevelvariable = "theProjectArray" > ... is the greater
   than sign a type-o?

After you've done those i would console.log(theProjectArray); right after it's defined.  Then console.log(theProjectArray);  again in your controller to ensure it's getting passed in properly.

Just for your reference here is a very basic example of a controller and a factory in angular calling a CFC.  Since i've been doing things this way the only time i use ColdFusion is to retrieve data and model it.  It's simplified my code and logic quite a bit and has allowed me to do a lot more now that i'm not leaning on ColdFusion.

```
var myapp = angular.module("test.myapp", [])


    myapp.controller("MyController", function($scope, getevent) {
        $scope.myData = {};
        $scope.myData.doUpdate = function(item, event) {

            getevent.GetProgram(item).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                             console.log(data.DATA);
                                              $scope.test = data.DATA;
                                              $scope.test.DATE = new Date(data.DATA.DATESTART);
                                          });

            getevent.GetProgram(item).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                               console.log("FAILED: "+item);
                                               alert("AJAX failed!");
                                           });
        }
    });




    myapp.factory('getevent', function($http){
        return {
                GetProgram: function(item) {
                    var programInfo = '/foundation/cfc/calendar.cfc?method=getevent&eventid='+item;
                    return $http.get(programInfo);
                }
                };
    });
```